# assembly resources

Tags: assembly

Could you give some guidance for good resources (books, online tutorials) about embedded assembly in C/C++ for windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're asking about is called inline assembler, not embedded. You can include inline assembly code using the __asm keyword in C/C++. See [MSDN inline assembler article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93(VS.80).aspx) for some info.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best win32 assembly sites around: http://win32assembly.online.fr/